# How to add hyperlink using json-as-xlsx library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, xlsx

I want to export the json data into an excel data and there is one column (name = Link) and in each data there should be a clickable link . i want to set hyperlink on that link

(Library used => json-as-xlsx    )

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
   
 
data = [
           {
             sheet: "Tasks",
             columns: [
             { label: "Status", value: (row) =>row.status_description==="completed"?"Pending                 Approval":"Accepted"},
            { label: "Req Date", value: (row) => moment(row.created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss')},
             { label: "Task Name", value: (row) => row.fields.find(o=>o.label==="Task name")?.value },
             { label: "Title", value: (row) => row.name },
            { label: "Content Type", value: (row) => row.fields.find(o=>o.label==="Content type")?.value },
            { label: "Final word count", value: (row) => row.word_count },
            { label: "Link", value: (row) =>  `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${row.doc}`,type:"hyperlink"}
                                        
                                    ],
                                    content: response.items,
                                }
                            ]
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
let filename = `${reqData.query.project_name}-${moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}`
                        let settings = {
                            fileName: filename, // Name of the resulting spreadsheet
                            extraLength: 1, // A bigger number means that columns will be wider
                            writeMode: 'writeFile', // The available parameters are 'WriteFile' and 'write'. This setting is optional. Useful in such cases https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/solutions/output#example-remote-file
                            writeOptions: {}, // Style options from https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#writing-options
                            RTL: false, // Display the columns from right-to-left (the default value is false)
                        }
        
                        let filepath = path.join(__dirname, `../../../${filename}.xlsx`);
                        
                        
        
                        let callback = function (sheet) {
                            
                            console.log("Download complete:",sheet)
                            resolve({filepath: filepath, filename: `${filename}.xlsx`});
                        }
                        
        
                        jsonAsXlsx(data, settings, callback)
                        
        
                    }).catch((err) => reject(err));
```